# Yii. Не сохраняются поля пормы

Tags: php, yii

Здравствуйте. 
У меня есть моделька `User` и `Contact`. Добавил в форму `User` два поля ( телефон и адрес с модельки `Contact`) все сохраняется и редактируется. Но до недавнего момента уже два случая было что поля ( телефон и адрес с модельки `Contact`) не записались. Даже не знаю где искать проблему.

Comment: код давайте, мы же не телепаты

Answer (score 1):

Ищите проблему в валидаторе.

```
$model->errors вам в этом поможет.
```

Comment: Спасиба knes.